# How to set paths while scraping data from website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, pythonpath

I am scraping data [from this URL](https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United%20States). 
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
browser.get("https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United+States")
time.sleep(3)
data_row = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('base.startup')
for item in data_row:
    print('-'*100)
    company = item.find_element_by_class_name('name').text
    location = item.find_element_by_class_name('column.location').text
    print(company)
    print(location)
```

Can anyone please help me with? I am using Windows 10.

1. What should be the path of my file which i am collecting all data in?
2. Is this code right or is there another library available which scrapes data faster then BS or selenium?

Comment: Do you get any mistakes?

Comment: @LucasDamian yes it shows path error basically i don't know how to assign path in this code and in this line chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'

Comment: if your project low-level complex then uses  Lxml is a high-performance, production-quality HTML and XML parsing library. When you are dealing with Core Javascript featured website then Selenium would be the best choice. if you just want to scrape data of company and location then Beautiful Soup would be the great choice for you.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara this URL is not static its dynamic however i have tried HTML XML in excel still not able to get data plus i am newbie so that would be great if you can tell me how to use this things with example or in a more elaborate mennor. thank you

Comment: do you want to save data to file?

Comment: @ManaliKagathara yes i want so save all data in a google spreadsheet file in this format   Company column ,Joined Column,Location Column , Market Column, Website Column,total raised column  in short  i want column wise data in spreadsheet or excel file :) from this url : https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United+States

Comment: when I try to scrape data with URL, it's giving me an anti-captcha.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara yes because when you go to inspect under this page it shows this page is not static its dynamic in short : if you see any webpage with live clock,page inspect changes in some amount of time so that's  basically happens with angel list website as well thats why its happening or maybe website has some anti bot script. i am working on this project since 7  months since i haven't found out single solution lol  , help if u can .. thanks

Comment: you can use a proxy because after some request it's giving  recaptcha

Comment: @ManaliKagathara can you tell me if there is any another option which can help avoid ceptcha  if you aware of any? and can you please show me which code you using ?